# RTSP Protocol for tv live streaming

Tags: android, hyperlink, streaming, rtsp, television

this code make a streaming for rtsp link but it doesn't work for my link but works for other one

link worked :  rtsp://masds03.htc.com.tw/99min_H264.3gp

my link that not worked : rtsp://mtaintl.mpl.miisolutions.net:1935/mtaintl-live-1/*definst*/mp4:MTA3_300k.stream

```
Uri stream = Uri.parse("rtsp://masds03.htc.com.tw/99min_H264.3gp");
    Intent videointent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,stream); 
    startActivity(videointent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link uses TCP port 1935. Which is a RTMP port number. Are you sure that your link uses RTSP as streaming protocol?

> rtsp://mtaintl.mpl.miisolutions.net:1935/mtaintl-live-1/definst/mp4:MTA3_300k.stream